# [DioErrorType.other]: SocketException: Failed host lookup when running flutter app in macos

Tags: macos, flutter

I am build the flutter app in macos(big sur) using this command:

```
~/apps/flutter/bin/flutter build macos --release
```

and I could found the app in the path: `/build/macos/Build/Products/Release/reddwarf_dict.app/Contents/MacOS/reddwarf_dict`, but when I run this app in macOS, shows error like this:

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: DioError [DioErrorType.other]: SocketException: Failed host lookup: 'api.example.top' (OS Error: nodename nor servname provided, or not known, errno = 8)
#0      DioMixin.assureDioError (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:819)
#1      DioMixin._dispatchRequest (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:678)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      DioMixin.fetch.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:586)
<asynchronous suspension>

#0      DioMixin.fetch.<anonymous closure> (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:618)
#1      _rootRunBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1452)
#2      _CustomZone.runBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1342)
#3      _FutureListener.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:175)
#4      Future._propagateToListeners.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:779)
#5      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:800)
#6      Future._completeError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:610)
#7      _SyncCompleter._completeError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:61)
#8      _Completer.completeError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:33)
#9      Future.any.onError (dart:async/future.dart:466)
#10     _rootRunBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1452)
#11     _CustomZone.runBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1342)
#12     _FutureListener.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:175)
#13     Future._propagateToListeners.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:779)
#14     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:800)
#15     Future._completeError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:610)
#16     Future._asyncCompleteError.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:666)
#17     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1428)
#18     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1328)
#19     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1236)
#20     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1276)
#21     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:40)
#22     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:49)
```

what should I do to fix this problem? what should I do to allow the network in macOS?

Answer (score 3):

I add this config to the file `macos/Runner/Release.entitlements` and fix this problem:

```
<key>com.apple.security.network.client</key>
<true/>
```

Comment: This didn't solve it for me. I even tried adding "<key>com.apple.security.network.server</key><true/>" but also didn't work.